# How to return current method in GCD block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, block

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self testGCD];
}

- (void)testGCD {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSLog(@"1");
        return;
    });
    NSLog(@"2");
}
```

The console printed 1 **and** 2.

What I want is only to print 1 the first time. I think maybe the `return` is not returning from the method, but instead from the block.

Is there any way I can return from the current method in this GCD block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the definition of `dispatch_once` then you gonna see that they are using `DISPATCH_EXPECT` to compare the `onceToken`. You can also use `if (onceToken != -1)` but `DISPATCH_EXPECT` optimises the code by telling the compiler that the probability of `onceToken == -1` is much much higher. This is called **Branch Prediction**

```
- (void)testGCD {
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  if (DISPATCH_EXPECT(onceToken, ~0l) != ~0l) {
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
      NSLog(@"1");
      return;
    });
  }
  else {
    NSLog(@"2");
  }
}
```

Comment: though it is possible that a particular invocation of this method will print nothing, if the first dispatch happened on another thread between our if check and our acquisition of the lock

Answer (score 3):

Use a block to get around the problem.

```
- (void)testGCD {
    __block void(^codeBlock)(void) = ^{ NSLog(@"2"); };
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        codeBlock = ^{ NSLog(@"1"); };
    });
    codeBlock();
}
```

Comment: Nice try, short cut and easy

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)testGCD {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    __block NSString *text = @"2";
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        text = @"1";
    });
    NSLog(@"%@", text);
}
```

Comment: Usually we put `NSLog` to represent our set of statements when we ask questions on SO. Although your answer is correct for just printing the `1` or `2` but if OP want to put 1 or more statement there instead of just printing then this will not work.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore you can read `text = @"2"` as one statement and `text = @"1"` as another. And put instead of them what you need

Comment: You're right if the both the statements are similar then above code will definitely but for different statements like statement1: `[self saveUserAndShowDialog];` and statement2:`[self showProgressAndHitApi];` would make life harder

Comment: @InderKumarRathore you can just put block or flag. `NSLog(@"%@", text);` you can read as `if (@"1" == text) `. like LGP suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement returns from the current enclosing scope, which in your case is the block.  You cannot return from the outer enclosing scope.

You can use a simple boolean flag to determine if this is the first time that the code has been executing, with a serial dispatch queue to ensure that it is thread-safe.

Something like:

```
- (void)testGCD {
    static dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyQueue", NULL);
    static bool firstRun = YES;

    dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
       if (firstRun) {
           NSLog(@"1);
           firstRun = NO;
       } else {
           NSLog(@"2");
       }
    });
}
```

By using a serial dispatch queue you ensure that there cannot be concurrent update of `firstRun`

Answer (score 0):

Block is like a completely separate method. A `return` in it will only return from the block. What you effectively seem to need is:

```
- (void)testGCD {
    static BOOL didTrigger = NO;

    if(didTrigger) {
        NSLog(@"2");
    }
    else {
        didTrigger = YES;
        NSLog(@"1");
    }
}
```

You might try to have a simple lock in your case but I am not sure how safe it would be in this case:

```
- (void)testGCD {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static BOOL didInvokeOnceBlock = NO;
    static BOOL didPassSkippedBlock = NO;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSLog(@"1");
        didInvokeOnceBlock = YES;
    });
    if(didInvokeOnceBlock && didPassSkippedBlock) {
        NSLog(@"2");
    }
    didPassSkippedBlock = YES;
}
```

But this still looks like it may have unstable results when multithreading. You might need to run this atomically for the result to be correct. What I see as potential issue is:

- Thread A and thread B start executing the same method.
- Thread A collects token and unlocks `didInvokeOnceBlock`
- Thread B skips block and unlocks `didPassSkippedBlock` but skips `NSLog(@"2");`
- Thread A invokes `NSLog(@"2");`